# WebUrl Download

Tags: c#, webclient

I am using c#.
I am trying to see if a web url Contains a string.
I am currently using

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                result = client.DownloadString(WebUrl);

            }
             if (result.Contains(String))
            {
                return true;
            }
```

I am doing this for about 300 Urls, is there a faster way or do I have to download each WebPage?

Comment: can you not just compare the weburl directly?

Comment: I do not know how or what you mean, could you please explain

Comment: well in your example you have a variable called `weburl`.. i thought you wanted to compare this at first..

Comment: Well you could use multi threads..

Comment: could either of you give a code example i am afraid i do not know what you mean

Comment: When you ask the question "Does a web URL contain a string?", are you asking "Does the URL contain a string?" (e.g. "Does 'http://www.google.com' contain 'gle.c'?"), or are you asking "Does the web page pointed to by a url contain a string?" (e.g. "Does Google's hope page contain the string "Business Solutions"?)